# Set start/default slide for bxslider

Tags: bxslider

Is there an option to set the start slide for bxslider? I checked the docs (http://bxslider.com/), but they don't seem to have such an option?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 0):

http://bxslider.com/options

startSlide
Starting slide index (zero-based)
default: 0
options: integer